# Multiple path in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I am trying nginx for the first time and I am running it locally. I have been able to get my services up but I have a puzzling question because I run a Microservice and during upgrade I want to be able to just block a particular service.

Now, each service has a a path eg

`\api\v1\wallet`
`\api\v1\card`

the issue I have is that both wallet and card path are in the same service.

If I have different paths would I have to duplicate or there's a way I could make it work better?

Here is my conf file

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }
http {

    server {

        listen 80;
        charset utf-8;

        location ~ ^/api/v1/user {
            rewrite ^/api/v1/user/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://user-service:3001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /api/v1/wallet/ {
            # rewrite /api/v1/wallet/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://wallet-service:3007/api/v1/wallet/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /api/v1/card/ {
            # rewrite /api/v1/wallet/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://wallet-service:3007/api/v1/card/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: What is the question? If an upstream server is not available nginx returns a proxy error no matter in what location it happens...

Comment: I’m asking if some sort of wild card can be accepted so I am not duplicating location with just different paths.

Comment: The regex and rewrite in the first location block are adding nothing to the functionality here however it is slightly more expensive and impacts the order in which the location blocks are processed. If you used an exact prefix match then the second 2 location blocks could be combined into a single prefix match on /api/v1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following setup:

```
location /api/v1/user {
    ...
}

location ~ ^/api/v1/(wallet|card)/$ {
    proxy_pass http://wallet-service:3007/api/v1/$1/;
    ...
}
```

Here we use regular expression capture to get path component into `$1` variable, and then use it in `proxy_pass` destination.

If you want to pass the rest of the URL via `proxy_pass`, then you need a second capture:

```
location ~ ^/api/v1/(wallet|card)/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://wallet-service:3007/api/v1/$1/$2;
    ...
}
```

Comment: the second suggestion returns `nginx-proxy_1            | 2022/03/06 13:11:48 [error] 32#32: *4 no resolver defined to resolve wallet-service, client: 172.20.0.1, server: , request: "GET /api/v1/card/health HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
nginx-proxy_1            | 172.20.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2022:13:11:48 +0000] "GET /api/v1/card/health HTTP/1.1" 502 157 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.1 Safari/605.1.15"`

Comment: The first one too returns 502 error for me.

Comment: You need to define name resolvers with `resolver` directive in nginx if you want to use names for your backend services. Alternative is to use IP addresses.